# OS X Lion disable rubber-band scrolling

Tags: macos, osx-lion

In OS X Lion, is there a way to disable rubber-band scrolling? This is the bounce effect when the content pane is scrolled beyond the top or bottom edge of the window. This only occurs with a trackpad.

Comment: Do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: Is there a cross posting feature?

Comment: No. Choose a site and stick with it, or ask a moderator to migrate your question when you don't get answers.

Comment: And what's wrong posting the same question on multiple sites?

Comment: Community consensus is to [not allow it](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2807/shouldnt-cross-posting-be-allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way is to turn of inertia scrolling. System Preferences > Universal Access > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options > Scrolling > without intertia

Answer (score 0):

Inertia scrolling is *NOT* the same as the elasticity effect when you reach the top or bottom of a page, in an app that supports it (like Safari 5.1.)

That being said, we have a built in way to turn off inertia scrolling.  We do NOT have a way to turn off the elasticity effect, if we're using input devices that support gestures.

I have found [this CSS snippet](http://www.smilingsouls.net/Blog/20110804114957.html) that apparently disables it:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now to figure out how to implement the CSS rule in every web page we visit... probably via a Safari extension, like QuickStyle or NinjaKit.

QuickStyle: http://canisbos.com/quickstyle

Comment: Also see: http://mir.aculo.us/2011/07/29/prevent-rubber-band-scrolling-for-single-page-apps-in-safari-5-1/

Answer (score 0):

Disable rubberbanding, but not vanishing scrollbars:

```
defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false
```

... and restore:

```
defaults delete -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding
```

This does not impact Safari nor iTunes, which use their own always-on rubberband system (possibly not using NSScrollView at all, or forcing rubberbanding to be on).

(also, this belongs to http://apple.stackexchange.com)